# Creating density plots using ggplot2 and purrr; colour of density line based on group

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr, density-plot

I am using a combination of ggplot2 and purrr in R Studio to loop through a dataframe and generate density plots. Here is a mock dataframe, similar to the structure of what I am working with:-

```
#load relevant libraries

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(gridExtra)

#mock dataframe
set.seed(123)
Duration<-floor(rnorm(1000, mean=200, sd=50))
DateTime<-seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2020-08-01 01:00:00", tz = Sys.timezone()), length.out = 1000, by = "hours")
df<-cbind(Duration,DateTime)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
df$Duration<-as.integer(df$Duration)
df$DateTime<-seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2020-08-01 01:00:00", tz = Sys.timezone()), 
                        length.out = 1000, by = "hours")#re-doing this to stop the annoying change back to numeric
df$WeekNumber<-isoweek(df$DateTime)
#create a "period" column
setDT(df)[WeekNumber>=31 & WeekNumber <=32, Period:="Period 1"]
df[WeekNumber>=33 & WeekNumber <=35, Period:="Period 2"]
df[WeekNumber>=36 & WeekNumber <=37, Period:="Period 3"]
df$Period<-factor(df$Period, levels = c("Period 1", "Period 2", "Period 3"))
```

And here is the code which uses purrr to loop through the dataframe to generate a density plot for each week:-

```
densplot<-df %>%
  group_by(WeekNumber) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  pull() %>% 
  # run map() instead of for()
  map(~{
    df %>%
      # filter for each value 
      filter(WeekNumber == .x) %>%
            # run unique density plot
      ggplot(aes(group=WeekNumber)) +
      geom_density(aes(Duration))+
      ggtitle(paste0("Week ",.x," duration"), subtitle = "Log10")+
      scale_x_log10()
  })

#call grid.arrange to create a faceted version of the plot
do.call(grid.arrange,densplot)
```

Which gives this:-

[image: Result of running do.call(grid.arrange,densplot)]

What I am trying to do is colour the density lines by "Period" for aid of interpretation. This would be easy enough using ggplot2 on it's own but I would like to use it in my purrr pipeline. However, if I specify `ggplot(aes(group=WeekNumber, colour=Period))` or `geom_density(aes(Duration))`, I get this:-
[image: Wrong outcome]

Plus, a legend for each individual plot, which does look untidy. I would like to be able to colour each individual Period and a single legend displaying the colour of all three Periods (perhaps placed on the right hand side). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using facet_wrap()?

Comment: Normally I would do my best to avoid using this kind of purrr solution and just use facet_wrap(). However, for the data I work with, I find that this purrr solution is good when needed to make lots of iterations and multiple graphs per iteration. I realise that the example I have provided is not great but trying to keep things minimal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use `facet_wrap()` in order to avoid issues with colors. Here the code for your options:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% mutate(WeekNumber=paste0("Week ",WeekNumber," duration")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Duration,group=WeekNumber,color=Period)) +
  geom_density()+
  scale_x_log10()+
  facet_wrap(.~WeekNumber,scales='free')
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:** If you want to iterate, you can adapt a list strategy by splitting your `df` by period. Then using a function for the plot and `patchwork` package you can get the expected plot. As additional remark, if you wish different colors you can hack the pipeline by defining the colors in your dataframe before splitting. I did in a practical way but you could use a color palette if more periods are present. Here the code:

```
library(patchwork)
#Add Colors to df
dfcol <- data.frame(Period=unique(df$Period),color=c('blue','red','green'),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Add to df
df$Colors <- dfcol[match(df$Period,dfcol$Period),"color"]
#Approach 2
#Create a list
List <- split(df,df$WeekNumber)
#Plot function
myplot <- function(x)
{
  #Extract color
  mycol <- unique(x$Colors)
  #Plots
  p1 <- ggplot(x,aes(x=Duration,group=WeekNumber,color=Period)) +
    geom_density()+
    scale_x_log10()+
    scale_color_manual(values = mycol)+
    ggtitle(paste0("Week ",unique(x$WeekNumber)," duration"), subtitle = "Log10")+
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())
  return(p1)
}
#Apply
L1 <- lapply(List,myplot)
#Wrap plots
combined <- wrap_plots(L1,ncol = 3)
combined + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. Usually I would use facet_wrap() in most circumstances. However, regarding the the data that I work with (I realise I could have created a better reproducible example), I need to use the purrr solution to make many iterations of this. Is there any reason why purrr wont allow me to colour the lines in the way that I specify?

Comment: @RobinTurkington I think there is a way to iterate and color the variable using lists but not purrr, you will get the same iteration style, is it valid to add an approach like that?

Comment: @RobinTurkington I have added an update, maybe it can helpful for you!!!

Comment: Thank you for providing the update, this worked perfectly and gave me the outcome I wanted!